# Why WebLogic Admin Server tries to shutdown managed servers directly first, instead of doing it through node manager?

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

Normally Admin Server issues start command to managed server using Node Manager.

But according to the Oracle documentations, for shutdown, Admin Server first tries to connect to managed server and tries to shutdown. If that fails, it ask node manager to shutdown the relevant managed server.
(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13740/overview.htm#NODEM135)

Why Admin server tries to connect to managed server directly in this case?
If it does try to contact managed server to shutdown it, what is the protocol it uses for it?

Answer (score 0):

It tries to perform graceful shutdown first so in-flight work is not lost. Under the hood it remotely invokes "shutdown" operation fron ServerRuntime Mbean. If this fails for some reason sever process is killed on OS level with use of Node Manager.

For inter domain communication WebLogic uses T3 protocol(RMI like).